# Ext and Krull dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, $I$ is a proper ideal of $R$ and $M$ is f.g. $R$-module. I want to find an example such that if  $c:=\sup\{i\in \mathbb{N_0} \mid \textrm{Ext}_R^i(R/I,M)\neq 0\}$ and $c$ is finite then $c\gneqq \dim(R)$.

thanks for help

Comment: Sorry, but I'm finding it very hard to parse the question. Reading it literally, any example where $c$ is infinite but $\dim(R)$ is finite would be an example, but I'm sure that's not what you mean. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "the converse": again, reading it literally, changing your $A\Rightarrow B$ statement to $B\Rightarrow A$ doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Since $c\leqslant \mathrm{gldim}(R)$, you must have that $\mathrm{gldim}(R)=\infty$; otherwise, $R$ would be regular.